# The sum of integrals of a function and its inverse: $\int_{0}^{a}f+\int_{f(0)}^{f(a)}f^{-1}=af(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Regarding real numbers, the following appears to be true, or at least true with some modifications. Could you help me for the proof? $$\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_{f(0)}^{f(a)}f^{-1}(x)dx=af(a)$$

Comment: What do you mean, by "true with some modifications"? (pretty much everything is true with some modifications...)

Comment: @ClementC. To explain, I tested with my pen by drawing some graphs, and all of them seemed to fit that equality. But still I may have made some mistakes or the equality may not be true under some corner cases I missed.

Comment: @ClementC. If the equality can be proven in most general sense with any type of modifications then I feel there is nothing wrong with this type of question i.e. the OP might want to know about these modifications only.

Comment: Given the phrasing of the question (without any additional detail), it's definitely vague. At least pointing out in the body of the question why the OP believe in this equality, and what sort of "modifications" may be in order (assumptions on $f$, such as regularity/smoothness? Or modifications to the equality itself?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geometrically, this equality represents:

The area of the rectangle with side lengths $a\times f(a)$ is equal to the sum of the area below the graph of $f(x),\,x\in[0,a]$ and the area above the graph of $f(x)$, which completes the rectangle. The later area is in fact the area below the inverse of $f$ in the interval $[0,f(a)]$.

**Addition:** The minimal requirements on the function $f$ are to be **continuous** and **injective** (differentiability is not needed), 
so that $f^{-1}$ makes sense. The condition of continuity is necessary, 
because otherwise it might happen that the range of $f$ is a strict subset of $[f(0),f(a)]$ 
and that $f^{-1}$ is not defined on a whole subinterval of $[f(0),f(a)]$ and so the integral $\int\limits_{f(0)}^{f(a)}{f^{-1}(y)dy}$ would not make sense. Now, because $f$ is continuous and a bijection from $[0,a]$ to $[f(0),f(a)]$ it follows that $f$ is strictly monotone.

Case 1 ($f$ is increasing) (look at the picture of Nikolaos Skout):

For each point $M(x_M,y_M)$ in the rectangle $a\times f(a)$ we have that either $y_M>f(x_M)$ ($M$ is above the graph of $f$, i.e $M\in B$) or $y_M\leq f(x_M)$ ($M$ is below the graph of $f$, i.e $M\in A$). Therefore $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup B=$ the rectangle $\{a\times f(a)\}$ $\quad\quad(*)$.

Also we have that according to the Rieman integral ($f$ and $f^{-1}$ are integrable as continuous functions defined on fintie intervals) that $\mu(A)=\int\limits_{0}^{a}{f(x)dx}$ and $\mu(B)=\int\limits_{f(0)}^{f(a)}{f^{-1}(y)dy}$, where $\mu$ denotes area. Now according to $(*)$ it follows that $\mu(\{a\times f(a)\})=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$.

Case 2 ($f$ is decreasing) is done analogously, having in mind that $\int\limits_{f(0)}^{f(a)}{f^{-1}(y)dy}$ is a negative value, because $f(0)>f(a)$.

Comment: This gives a nice interpretation, but formally one requires some assumptions about $f$ (for instance, continuity), I believe. (The "corner cases" the OP was referring to)

Comment: @ClementC.  I think continuity is enough, although I can not think of a way to prove it without differentiability.

Comment: ..and invertibility, of course.

Answer (score 5):

[image] A geometric approach is as follows: the integral 
$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$ is represented by the region A and the
$\displaystyle \int_{f(0)}^{f(a)}f^{-1}(x)dx$ is represented by 
the region B. Of course the sum of the areas of the above regions equals the whole area, that is af(a), as desired.

Comment: This is not true in general, though -- not for *any* $f$ at least. (Unless I'm mistaken, the argument ("Of Course") does require continuity of $f$, for instance)

Comment: The statement was given without any conditions. That means that we can either expect all the good things we want to happen (that is: $f$ one-to-one,  $f$ integrable and moreover, continuous, etc), either expect no nonditions at all. As far as I know this is a classic exercise and most of the times the necessary conditions are given as desired. Thanks a lot for pointing this out Clement.

Answer (score 2):

We assume $f$ has an inverse over the interval $(0,a)$ and both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are smooth. Letting $x = f^{-1}(y) \iff y = f(x)$, by substitution we have

$$\int_{f(0)}^{f(a)} f^{-1}(y) \, dy = \int_0^a x f'(x) dx$$

Using integration by parts, we have
$$\int_0^a x f'(x) dx = \int_0^a x df(x) = xf(x) \Big\vert_{x=0}^{x=a} - \int_0^a f(x) dx = af(a) - \int_0^a f(x) dx $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** (Assuming $f$ is differentiable). Differentiate the function $g$ defined by
$$
g(a) = \int_0^a f + \int_{f(0)}^{f(a)} f^{-1} - af(a) 
$$
(which is indeed differentiable as $f$ is).

In detail (place your mouse over the gray area to reveal its contents)

> $$g^\prime(a) = f(a) + f^\prime(a)\cdot f^{-1}(f(a)) - (af^\prime(a) + f(a)) = f(a) + af^\prime(a) - af^\prime(a) - f(a) = 0$$ using the chain rule to derive the second term. To conclude, observe that $g(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution based on some elements of Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration.

> ***Proposition:*** If  $f$ is strictly monotone increasing and continuous over the interval $[0,c]$, then for any $0\leq a\leq c$
> \begin{align}\int^a_0 f(x)\,dx + \int^{f(a)}_{f(0)} f^{-1}(y)\,dy = a f(a)\tag{0}\label{zero}\end{align}

*Proof:* As $f$ is strictly monotone increasing continuous on $[0,c]$, $f$ is invertible on $[f(0),f(c)]$. There are unique Borel finite continuous measures $\mu_f$ and $\mu_{f^{-1}}$ on $(0,c]$ and $(f(0), f(c)]$ respectively such that $f(s)-f(t)=\mu_f((s,t])$ and $f^{-1}(v)-f^{-1}(u)=\mu_{f^{-1}}((u,v])$ for all $0\leq t<s\leq c$ and $f(0)<u<v\leq f(c)$. Let $0<a\leq c$. Notice that

$$\{(x,y): 0<x\leq a, f(0)<y\leq f(x)\}=\{(x,y):f(0)<y\leq f(a), f^{-1}(y)\leq x\leq a\}$$

An application of [Lebesgue integration by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3724004/121671) and Fubini-Tonelli's there yield

\begin{align}
\int_{(0,a]} f(x)\,dx &= af(a)-\int_{(0,a]} x\mu_f(dx)\\
&=af(a)-\int_{(0,a]}\int_{(f(0),f(x)]}\mu_{f^{-1}}(dy)\,\mu_f(dx)\\
&=a f(a)-\int_{(f(0),f(a)]}\int_{[f^{-1}(y),a]}\mu_f(dx)\,\mu_{f^{-1}}(dy)\\
&=af(a)-\int_{(f(0),f(a)]}(f(a)-y)\mu_{f^{-1}}(dy)\\
&=af(a)-f(a)a+\int_{(f(0),f(a)]}y\mu_{f^{-1}}(dy)\\
&=f(a)a-\int_{(f(0),f(a)]} f^{-1}(y)\,dy
\end{align}

---

**Remark:** With very little additional effort, from \eqref{zero} we obtain the following well known result:

> (Young's inequality) If $f$ is strictly monotone continuous over $[0,c]$, then for any $0\leq a\leq c$ and $f(c)\leq b\leq f(c)$
> $$\int^a_0f(x)\,dx+\int^b_{f(0)}f^{-1}(y)\,dy\geq ab$$
> with equality when $b=f(a)$.

If $f(0)\leq b\leq f(a)$, then
\begin{align}
\int^{f^{-1}(b)}_0 f(x)\,dx+\int^b_{f(0)} f^{-1}(y)\,dy&=bf^{-1}(b)=ba+b(f^{-1}(b)-a)
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
ab&=\int^{f^{-1}(b)}_0 f(x)\,dx+b(a-f^{-1}(b)) + \int^b_{f(0)} f^{-1}(y)\,dy\\
&< \int^{f^{-1}(b)}_0 f(x)\,dx + \int^a_{f^{-1}(b)}f(x)\,dx+\int^b_{f(0)} f^{-1}(y)\,dy\\
&=\int^a_0 f(x)\,dx + \int^b_{f(0)} f^{-1}(y)\,dy
\end{align}

Similarly, if $f(a)<b\leq f(c)$, then
\begin{align}
\int^a_0 f(x)\,dx+\int^{f(a)}_{f(0)}f^{-1}(y)\,dy=af(a)=ab+a(f(a)-b)
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
ab& =\int^a_0 f(x)\,dx+\int^{f(a)}_{f(0)}f^{-1}(y)\,dy+a(b-f(a))\\
&< \int^a_0 f(x)\,dx+\int^{f(a)}_{f(0)}f^{-1}(y)\,dy+\int^b_{f(a)}f^{-1}(y)\,dy\\
&=\int^a_0f(x)\,dx+\int^b_{f(0)}f^{-1}(y)\,dy
\end{align}